# Formula issues when working out chances of getting certain marks

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

$$P(X = k) = \binom{N}{k} (0.5)^k (0.5)^{N-k} = \binom{N}{k} (0.5)^N$$

Using formula above, I have got the following results for chances for getting certain percentage on a $50$ question paper, each question containing yes/no options to choose from.

- $70\%$ or greater $= 0.03$ ($3\%$)
- $60\%$ or greater $= 0.8790$
- $50\%$ or greater $= 2.9191$
- $40\%$ or greater $= 1.2971$

To me this doesn't seem to make sense as more of a chance getting $50\%$ or greater than $40\%$ or greater and if I convert them into percentages then I get ridiculous percentages.

I want to know if others are getting same answers or am I doing something badly wrong.

Comment: You have asked several almost identical questions about these yes/no tests with $50$ questions and the binomial distribution. Please stop it.

Comment: @TMM I will stop it, apologies. Can you please state if the answers I got correct or not. If incorrect can you tell me answers, then I don't have to ask this question anymore. Again apologies, it is just that I have been stuck on this for 3 days

Comment: If anything is unclear about answers to your earlier questions, then you should leave comments to those answers asking for explanations.

Comment: Most of the answers are not right. Certainly nothing $\gt 1$ can be right. I had supplied earlier the answer for $50\%$, it was about $0.56$, and for $70\%$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It is when I try to do the formula myself on calculator I do not get same answers. Looking at answer below are they correct and if so is the relevant percentages 0.3%, 10%, 56% and 94%?

Comment: I checked only the $50\%$ and $70\%$. They are right. The computation is a little unpleasant by hand, so have software do it for you. Find Wolfram Alpha (free online). For $70\%$ or above, type this: sum from k=35 to k=50 of binom(50,k)/2^(50). It should give you the answer to a zillion decimal places.  For other similar questions, make the obvious adjustment.

Comment: Thanks, I used the Wolfram Alpha software and worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add ranges of individual probablillities (you can also use cumulated distribution as $P(x>=X)=1-P(x<X)=1-F(X)$ ). I think from the picture below you will get the right idea.

[image]